# How to remove all the elements of list from a string?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of strings like

```
l1 = ['John', 'London', '219980']
```

I want to remove elements of this list from given string say:

```
s1 = "This is John Clay. He is from London with 219980"
```

I know I can do it like

```
for l in l1:
    s1 = s1.replace(l, "")
```

But if the list is big it takes too much time. 
Is there any other alternative solution for this?

Desired Output:

```
'This is  Clay. He is from  with '
```

**EDIT**:

The list is made in such a way that all the elements from the list are present in string(sentence).

Comment: you can use regex

Comment: I'm not sure how I can use `re` with `list`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you simply use regex-or (`|`)

```
import re
l1 = ['John', 'London', '219980']
s1 = "This is John Clay. He is from London with 219980"
re.sub('|'.join(l1),'',s1)
```

in case your l1 contains `|` you can escape it with `r'\|'` first

Answer (score 1):

Using regular expressions and in particular 
[`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub), you can try:

```
import re

l1 = ['John', 'London', '219980']
s1 = "This is John Clay. He is from London with 219980"
p = '|'.join(l1)  # pattern to replace
re.sub(p, '', s1)
# 'This is  Clay. He is from  with '
```